# How do I render different pages with variables on post request of login with passport.js local authentication?(Express)

Tags: javascript, express, passport.js, pug

I am trying to login the user with passport.js authentication and on success I redirect the user to the last page that comes from a variable inside the login page, and on failure I re-render the login page with a message, I tried to do it but I fail, here what I did:

```
router.post('/login', 
  body('backurl').trim().escape(),

  (req,res,next) =>{
    passport.authenticate('local', (err,user)=>{
      if(err){return next(err)}
      if(!user){
        return res.render('login', {message: 'Unable to login, the password or the username are wrong'})
      }
      if(req.body.backurl == null){
        return res.redirect('/yourcourses')
      }
      return res.redirect(req.body.backurl)
    });
  }
);
```

it just keeps endlessly loading and nothing comes out, what is wrong with my code?

Thanks!

Comment: That can get annoying for users. It's generally a better idea to make an AJAX request and if the response is AOK, continue forward. If failure, read out the error code? Annoyance comes into play when they have to re-type their login to keep messing it up and it's costing you requests served.

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a definitive reference for `passport.authenticate`, but all the example in https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/ show it as a middleware, so I think you'll need to use it as such:

```
router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  (req, res, next) => {
    req.body('backurl').trim().escape();
    if (!req.user) {
      return res.render('login', {
        message: 'Unable to login, the password or the username are wrong'
      });
    }
    if (req.body.backurl == null) {
      return res.redirect('/yourcourses');
    }
    
    return res.redirect(req.body.backurl);
  }
);
```